# How can I keep a serializable class backwards compatible when switching away from an auto-implemented property

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I need to change MyProperty so that it is no longer auto-implemented. My question is, will this break compatibility? In other words, will MyClass instances serialized before this change be correctly deserialized after this change? Do I have to do anything to guarantee this? What rules govern how this works?

For reference, I want something like:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, int> _myProperty;
    public Dictionary<string, int> MyProperty
    {
        get { return this._myProperty; }
        set { Validate(value); this._myProperty = value; }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I tried this specific toy example and it seems to work, but that doesn't give me much confidence because my real example(s) are more complex. I'd like to understand the underlying rules so that I can make an educated guess before testing.

Comment: Why not check it yourself?

Comment: Yes, it is a breaking change.  Binary serialization only knows about fields, it doesn't care about properties.  Your original field had an unspeakable name, `MyClass::<MyProperty>k__BackingField`.  It doesn't anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant is there any way to avoid this? E. g. with attributes or something to customize the serialization? Also, if this is breaking then why does it work in the case above?

Comment: Just keep the original version of the class around.  Pain yourself a bit how old vs new are going to interact, *extern alias* is a tool handed to you.  Universal problem, versioning is hard and nobody will help you paper over the differences between "crappy old version" and "wonderful new way to do it".

Comment: This is why you should not use `BinaryFormatter` for persistent storage, it does not handle versioning very well at all. Stock `BinaryFormatter` without a custom `Binder` or `SurrogateSelector` or using `UnsafeDeserialize` should only be used for IPC on the same machine (IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [custom deserialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.110).aspx) to pull out the field's value by its old name.

Or, make this auto property virtual and derive a class from it. That way you can use `base.MyProperty` to access the auto-named backing field. You can have a new field in the derived class that is used preferably.